# Properties of the inverse stable subordinator

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, levy-processes

I just need a good reference and/or some more well-known results (which I don't know yet) for the following situation.

Let $\alpha\in(0,1)$. If I have an $\alpha$-stable subordinator $\mathbf{X}$, i.e. a nondecreasing, pure-jump Levy process with $\mathbf{X}(1)\sim G_{\alpha}$, where $G_{\alpha}$ is a one-sided $\alpha$-stable law. Which properties does $\mathbf{X}^{-1}$ (right-continuous inverse or first-passage time) have?

I heared it is a continuous process? That it is nondecreasing is evident, but at which points is it strictly increasing? And "how" many such points are there?

Thank's a lot!

Comment: I'm not an expert but page 19 of Jean Bertoin's *Subordinators: Examples and Applications* speaks about $X^{-1}$ stating that it is continuous and its set of points of increase equals the range of $X$

Comment: Thank's! I found the part and it answers most of my questions. But does this make paths of the inverse subordinator a "devil's staircase"? Since such a path is continuous, unbounded and increases only at countably many points?